# Complete Sample for ActionMailer to send email with GMAIL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, actionmailer

I would like to test my ActionMailer class, but don't have an smtp server.  I would like to use gmail to send such emails.  Could someone provide a sample with all the necessary configurations both on google and whatever config files in the app?

Answer (score 5):

GMail has only SSL SMTP available, so you should create a SSL SMTP connection through Net::SMTP.

Check this article:

- [How to use GMail SMTP server to send emails in Rails ActionMailer](http://www.stephenchu.com/2006/06/how-to-use-gmail-smtp-server-to-send.html)

Answer (score 4):

I do this with SSMTP.  It acts as an SMTP server and proxies to a real SMTP server.  On Unix (Ubuntu hardy in this case) it makes the system sendmail work properly.

If you're also on Ubuntu, run `apt-get install ssmtp` to get it.

This is a sample config file based on mine.

```
#
# Config file for sSMTP sendmail
#
# The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
# Make this empty to disable rewriting.
root=postmaster

# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no 
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
#mailhub=aspmx.l.google.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587

# Where will the mail seem to come from?
rewriteDomain=example.com

# The full hostname
hostname=yourhostname.example.com

# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
# YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
# NO - Use the system generated From: address
FromLineOverride=YES

# should turn on SSL & auth to google's SMTP server
# TODO change this user
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
AuthUser=yourgoogleuser@example.com.com
AuthPass=yourgooglepassword
```

You will want to add this to your `environment.rb` or `production/environment.rb`:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Comment: I attempted this, but am getting the following error: 

Errno::EPIPE in UsersController#create
Broken pipe

I tested sendmail and ssmtp and can send email to addresses through the terminal outside of rails.  Do you have any insight into what may be causing this or what it means?  Googling returned no successful solution.

Comment: Thank you rails casts, this works: http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3